# Why so much data precision loss with "float" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to plot a graph in my Android application. The "entry()" function which takes in the x-axis value and y-axis value has declaration syntax as: **entry(float x, float y)**

Now, my problem with float in Kotlin is as follows:

I keep receiving data from another Bluetooth device wherein one of the data fields is a timestamp value (unsigned 32-bits). This timestamp value is in ms, I need to divide this value by 1000 and plot the x-axis values in "sec". However, I am loosing lot of precision with "float" data type in Kotlin.

For example, consider the following code:

```
/**
* You can edit, run, and share this code. 
* play.kotlinlang.org 
*/

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

fun main() {
   var mArrayList:ArrayList<UByte> = ArrayList()
   mArrayList.add(0xFF.toUByte())
   mArrayList.add(0xFF.toUByte())
   mArrayList.add(0xFF.toUByte())
   mArrayList.add(0xFF.toUByte())


   var intInc:UByte = 0.toUByte()
   var mTimeStamp:UInt 
   var mFloatVal:Float 
   var mDoubleVal:Double 

   for(i in 1..10){
       mArrayList.set(3, intInc)
       intInc = intInc.plus(2.toUByte()).toUByte()

       mTimeStamp = mArrayList.get(0).toUInt().shl(24)
       mTimeStamp = mTimeStamp.or(mArrayList.get(1).toUInt().shl(16))
       mTimeStamp = mTimeStamp.or(mArrayList.get(2).toUInt().shl(8))
       mTimeStamp = mTimeStamp.or(mArrayList.get(3).toUInt().shl(0))

       mDoubleVal = mTimeStamp.toDouble()
       mDoubleVal = mDoubleVal.div(1000)
       mFloatVal = mDoubleVal.toFloat()
       println("mTimeSTamp = $mTimeStamp, mDoubleVal = $mDoubleVal, mFloatVal = $mFloatVal")
   }   
}
```

Code output:

```
mTimeSTamp = 4294967040, mDoubleVal = 4294967.04, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967042, mDoubleVal = 4294967.042, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967044, mDoubleVal = 4294967.044, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967046, mDoubleVal = 4294967.046, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967048, mDoubleVal = 4294967.048, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967050, mDoubleVal = 4294967.05, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967052, mDoubleVal = 4294967.052, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967054, mDoubleVal = 4294967.054, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967056, mDoubleVal = 4294967.056, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
mTimeSTamp = 4294967058, mDoubleVal = 4294967.058, mFloatVal = 4294967.0
```

By comparing above mDoubleVal and mFloatVal, it seems there is too much data precision loss. I need accurate float value to 3 decimal places. How can I achieve this? I understand that we cannot exactly represent floating point numbers because of limitations in representation, but it is surprising to see this limitation starting with the first decimal point.

Comment: hmm, are you not aware that float is stored in 32 bit, double is stored in 64 bit? plus floting point is inaccurate by nature...

Comment: If you're forced to use floats (and not longs or doubles), you can get back precision by using numbers much closer to 0. Assuming your timestamps represent milliseconds since January 1970, but all values are actually measures taken today or yesterday, you can just shift all values so that the timestamp 0 is, let's say, yesterday at 00:00. Once you have shifted the long timestamps to this new origin, cob-nverting them t floats should give you more precise values.

Comment: Normally you'd be well advised to use a precise type such as long or BigDecimal for time values.  (In the same way as you should _never_ use floating-point for money values!)  But if MPAndroidChart requires floats, then you'll have to do the best you can; JB Nizet's idea of using an offset sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

A c/java/kotlin float is an IEEE single precision floating point number. Therefore so you get 24 bits (23 stored mantissa bits, plus an implicit leading 1) or about 7 decimal digits of precision. As you use more digits before the decimal point you get less after the decimal point.

Comment: Yes, the before decimal number, "4294967.0" I am trying to print does have 24 bits. But can you elaborate why only 24 bits or about 7 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: A single-precision floating-point number is stored in 32 bits.  (This is standard across many languages, not just Java/Kotlin.)  That uses 24 bits to store the mantissa (AKA significand; the main part of the number, excluding the leading bit which is always 1), and 8 bits to store the exponent (the power of 2 to multiply the significand by).  2^24 = 16777216, giving 7–8 decimal digits of precision.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Actually there are only 23 bits of mantissa stored (plus 8 exponent bits and one sign bit). However the "implicit 1" and some trickery around extreme exponent values means the effective mantissa size is 24 bits.

Comment: and the IEEE single and double precision floating point formats have become baked-into basically the entire computer industry. It's not just a matter of programming languages, but also a matter of hardware.

Comment: @Naresh Kotlin uses the Java ecosystem, throughout the Java ecosystem float is 32 bits. Just use Double (64 bits). Since these are IEEE standards they aren't unique to Java either, many languages use 32 bits for float and 64 for double.